# Is there any way to find the Aave health factor for a given address (not mine) at a given block?

Tags: etherscan, aave

**Is there any way to find the Aave health factor for a given address (not mine) at a given block?
e.g. Find out the exact “health factor” for the address 0x0000006daea1723962647b7e189d311d757Fb793 at block 12224887.**

Thought process for this initially went in 2 directions:

1. *Can calculate this factor given some other information*
2. *Can find health factor for this address using some online tool*

First, taking route 1: Started with reading the Aave protocol whitepaper. Here I found a formula for health factor.

Then found Liquidation Threshold Values in a graph from Aave documentation.

Then used Etherscan and Ethplorer to look for the address and get transaction or financial data. Found the address on both sites, but couldn’t get the information I wanted, with respect to collateral in ETH and Total Borrows in ETH.

Found out that Block 13532886 was mined on Nov-01-2021 06:58:47 PM +UTC after looking at time-stamps.

Figured I’d need to get Collateral and Total Borrows in ETH from this time period to get the Health Factor for this address at this block, but, to no avail.

*Switched to Method 2*

Found a site called Hal: https://9000.hal.xyz/recipes/aave-time-based-track-your-health-factor

And found the following health factor for today for the given address, but not the health factor for the block.

And that is as far as I got.

Anyone got any ideas how to find this information out?

Comment: There's this site that gives you the hf for a given address. https://gmi.tools/aave

Did you find a solution? I'm interested to cause I dislike the idea to have to signup to 9000.hal or similar. I just need some automated alert that i can host myself like a telegram bot.

Comment: Just found out that gmi.tools is using zapper api to get aave info for a give address. Something like https://api.zapper.fi/v1/protocols/aave-v2/balances?addresses%5B%5D=<address>&network=<network>&api_key=96e0cc51-a62e-42ca-acee-910ea7d2a241

Answer (score 1):

It is relatively simple to query this info from the blockchain. The [LendingPool.sol#L947](https://github.com/aave/aave-protocol/blob/4b4545fb583fd4f400507b10f3c3114f45b8a037/contracts/lendingpool/LendingPool.sol#L947) has the method `getUserAccountData` where you find the `health factor`.

Typically, when you query the blockchain you receive the data for **`latest`** block, but if you have an **`archive`** node, you can specify any block number to get the data for this block. You can use any `web3` library to fetch the infos from [contracts](https://docs.aave.com/developers/deployed-contracts/deployed-contracts). Here is the example for [`0xweb`](https://github.com/0xweb-org/0xweb) which you use as `cli` or `api`.

##### Terminal

```sh
$ npm i 0xweb -g
$ 0xweb i 0x7d2768dE32b0b80b7a3454c06BdAc94A69DDc7A9 --name AavePoolV2 --chain eth
$ 0xweb i 0x87870Bca3F3fD6335C3F4ce8392D69350B4fA4E2 --name AavePoolV3 --chain eth
$ 0xweb c read AavePoolV3 getUserAccountData --user 0x0000006daea1723962647b7e189d311d757Fb793
```

The output would be smth. like:

```json
{
  "totalCollateralBase": "9988785562076",
  "totalDebtBase": "3707556318467",
  "availableBorrowsBase": "3684144997469",
  "currentLiquidationThreshold": "7600",
  "ltv": "7400",
  "healthFactor": "2047568903907283903"
}
```

> The `healthFactor` is in wei (`18` digits). For repaid accounts the `healthFactor` will be a huge number (max `uint256`)

To read the `getUserAccountData` at a specific block or date (*blocknumber will be auto-resolved*) add the `--block` parameter:

```bash
$ 0xweb c --block 16111729 read AavePoolV2 getUserAccountData --user 0x0000006daea1723962647b7e189d311d757Fb793
$ 0xweb c --block "2022-12-04T13:26:59Z" read AavePoolV2 getUserAccountData --user 0x0000006daea1723962647b7e189d311d757Fb793
```

##### TypeScript

By installing a contract you can import it from the code, but before, initialize the dependencies with `0xweb init` in the projects folder, after that

```typescript
import { Config } from '@dequanto/Config';
import { AavePoolV2  } from '@0xweb/eth/AavePoolV2/AavePoolV2';
import { $bigint } from '@dequanto/utils/$bigint';


async function read () {
    // reads RPC urls and others, modifiable with `0xweb config -e`
    await Config.fetch()

    let aave = new AavePoolV2();
    let userData = await aave.getUserAccountData('0x0000006daea1723962647b7e189d311d757Fb793');
    console.log('Health Factor: ', $bigint.toEther(userData.healthFactor, 18));

    // of for block/date
    let userDataByBlock = await aave
        .forBlock(16111729)
        .getUserAccountData('0x0000006daea1723962647b7e189d311d757Fb793');

    let userDataByDate = await aave
        .forBlock(new Date('2022-12-04T13:26:59Z'))
        .getUserAccountData('0x0000006daea1723962647b7e189d311d757Fb793');
}
```

> Per default, 0xweb uses Ankr's public node, it also has archive node, but is rate limited, to use your node modify the URL with `0xweb config -e`

Answer (score 0):

Try these links:

https://docs.aave.com/faq/borrowing#what-is-the-health-factor

https://docs.aave.com/risk/asset-risk/risk-parameters#health-factor

for aave's explanation